# Are we allowed to use classifiers to estimate the outcome in the first stage of Double Machine Learning when the outcome is binary?

Tags: causality, binary-data, treatment-effect, confounding

It is clear to me how to proceed when the outcome is continuous, since the EconML and all other references I checked work with this type of examples (continuous outcome case). We simply apply a regressor to estimate it. However when the outcome is binary, should/could we employ classifiers?

When the treatment is discrete, it seems that, yes, we are allowed since that's exactly the default option in the EconML documentation for the [LinearDML](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/_autosummary/econml.dml.LinearDML.html#econml.dml.LinearDML) class.

> model_t (estimator or ‘auto’, default ‘auto’) – The estimator for fitting the treatment to the features. If estimator, it must implement fit and predict methods; If ‘auto’, LogisticRegressionCV will be applied for discrete treatment, and WeightedLassoCV/WeightedMultiTaskLassoCV will be applied for continuous treatment.

However the same does not hold for the outcome model of the first stage. If we are not allowed to use a classifier, what is the underlying reason? I would greatly appreciate references on this topic.

Comment: I think yes you can use classifier as long as the classifier returns probabilities of classes, not classes themselves.

Comment: Perhaps the docs of [DoubleML](https://docs.doubleml.org/stable/guide/guide.html#guide) have something on this?